# Can non-HD Android devices output full HD over HDMI?

Tags: hdmi, video-out

What is the chance Android 4+ phone or tablet with physical HDMI-out connector will be able to output FullHD resolution if the device itself does not have FullHD screen? Are there any rules for this? What if the device's screen resolution is even smaller than 720p (like 800x480)?

Comment: The screen is irrelevant, it's down to what the camera hardware can handle. That's on a device by device basis depending on the rendering software and the hardware sensor. Probably not on anything dual core or less I'd wager, maybe not on others.

Comment: @RossC What has the camera got to do with anything?

Comment: @DanHulme Ross probably lost the "e.g.", and meant the camera as an example. If the camera cannot take Full HD, you cannot stream the camera image in Full HD.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any rules for this, so it's entirely up to the tablet in each particular case. I can give an example: the original Asus Eee Pad Transformer TF101 has a < 720p screen, and its HDMI output is a pixel-for-pixel mirror of the screen (i.e. the HDMI output is the same pixel size as the screen).